# I build flutter but there are errors in native-platform.dll and gradle

Tags: flutter, dart

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\bwa_cozy> flutter build apk

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not initialize native services.
> Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
  get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            4,5s
  Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
  PS C:\Users\Lenovo\bwa_cozy>
- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not initialize native services.
> Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 10 amd64.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
  get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            4,5s
  Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1